# how to use __PACKAGE__->config namespace in catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

```
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');
```

I have seen this statement in Root Controller `Root.pm` of my Catalyst application.
What I know about this is that, this statement is used to specify root controller.
Now I want to know is ,What else way is this statement used,
means Can I use this to specify other controller namespace? If yes,How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both questions are explained in the manual. Read [*Actions* in `Catalyst::Manual::Intro`](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst::Manual::Intro#Actions).

> #### Application Wide Actions
>
> […] The code `__PACKAGE__->config( namespace => '' );` makes the controller act as if its namespace is empty. […] an empty namespace makes many of the URL-matching attributes, such as `:Path` and `:Local` match at the start of the URL path (i.e. the application root).

---

> #### Overriding the namespace
>
> Note that `__PACKAGE__->config->(namespace => ... )` can be used to override the current namespace when matching. So `package MyApp::Controller::Example;` would normally use `example` as its namespace for matching, but if this is specially overridden with `__PACKAGE__->config( namespace => 'thing' );`, it matches using the namespace `thing` instead.

Comment: How can I use same in `Application.pm`? That is, I want to apply it to all controllers.